# Why do this port-scanner not give accurate results everytime?

Tags: node.js, asynchronous

Below is the code for my port-scanner which I have written in node. The problem is that it gives you correct result one time but it will skip a few open ports on other instances of running. The open ports it should list include 22, 80 and 443. Can you help me by running it a few times please?

```js
const async = require('async')
const net = require('net')
const timeout = 3000
const host = '192.30.253.113'
const openPorts = []
const concurrency = 100
const portsToScan = 2000

const q = async.queue(function(port, callback) {
  const client = net.createConnection({
    port: port,
    host: host
  }, () => {
    openPorts.push(port)
    client.destroy()
  })

  client.on('error', () => {
    client.destroy()
  })

  client.setTimeout(timeout, () => {
    client.destroy()
  })

  client.on('close', () => {
    callback()
  })
}, concurrency)

for (let port = 0; port <= portsToScan; port++) {
  q.push(port)
}

q.drain = () => {
  console.log(openPorts)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on the timeout you set... 3s is not a lot from where I am (ping > 1000ms tonight, it's a bad day, maybe that's why it's not working well from here). 
It's difficult to figure out the "perfect" parameters.

Note: there's no port 0, you can start your loop at 1.